# Second Dropdown List completely empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

The plan is to populate the second dropdown menu based on the item chosen in the first one. I developed the code below but unfortunately after I select an item in the first menu the second one remain empty. Can you help me out with the issue? Thanks in advance.

PS. If you want to check directly the issue you can visit my testing website at the following link: [click here](http://knowledge2go.altervista.org)

## Index.php

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#departures').on('change',function(){
        var depname = $(this).val();
        if(depname){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'prova2.php',
                data:'dep_name='+depname,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#arrivals').html(html); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#departures').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form action='index.php' method='post'>
<h2>Select Departure:</h2>
<select id="departures" name="departures" class="form-control" onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
        <option value="">--- Select Departure ---</option>

                    <?php
                        require('prova1.php');
                        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM departures"; 
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM arrivals"; 
                        $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
       while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){
     ?>   
     <option value="<?php echo $row1["dep_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $row1["dep_name"]; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>

</select>
<br>

<h2>Select Arrival:</h2>
<select id="arrivals" name="arrivals" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--- Select your Arrival ---</option>
</select>
<br>
<h2>Select # of passengers</h2>
<select name="passengers" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--- # of passengers ---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<br>

<h2>Select # of bags</h2>
<select name="bags" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--- # of bags ---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Get Selected Values' />
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $selected_val1 = $_POST['departures'];  
 $selected_val2 = $_POST['arrivals'];
 $selected_val3 = $_POST['passengers'];
 $selected_val4 = $_POST['bags'];    
 if ($selected_val3 < 4 AND $selected_val4 < 4){
 echo "You will drive with a taxi!"; 
 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM taxilist WHERE dep_name = '".$selected_val1."' AND arr_name = '".$selected_val2."'";
 } else {
 echo "You will drive with a van!";
 $query3 = "SELECT * FROM vanlist WHERE dep_name = '".$selected_val1."' AND arr_name = '".$selected_val2."'";
 }
 require('prova1.php');
 echo "<br>The price from " .$selected_val1. " to " .$selected_val2. " is: ";
 $result3 = $mysqli->query($query3);
  while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
  echo $row3['price'];
  }
 }
?>
```

### prova2.php

```html
<?php
require('prova1.php');
 
if(isset($_POST["departures"]) && !empty($_POST["departures"])){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE arr_name = ".$_POST['departures);
    
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    
    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select arrival</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['arr_name'].'">'.$row['arr_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Arrival not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$.ajax` posts `dep_name` and `prova2.php` expects `departures` parameter.

Comment: This appears to be a syntax error: `$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE arr_name = ".$_POST['departures);`. I believe `$_POST['departures)` should be `$_POST['departures'])`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yeah you are right. Thank you! Unfortunately it's not the only issue since it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

**prova2.php**

The variable from ajax is dep_name. used real_escape_string to Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

```
<?php
require('prova1.php');

$dep_name  = isset($_POST["dep_name"]) ? $_POST["dep_name"] : '';

// escape variables for security
$dep_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($dep_name);

if (!empty($dep_name)){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM states WHERE arr_name = '".$dep_name."'");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        $Return = '<option value="">Select arrival</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $Return .= '<option value="'.$row['arr_name'].'">'.$row['arr_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        $Return = '<option value="">Arrival not available</option>';
    }

    echo $Return;
}
?>
```